# actuate.Parameter is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, birt

I am integrating JSF with Birt report and able to connect with IHub server from Java code. Also got all the reports file inside some particular folder and displaying the report file name it into the JSF Datalist .Now when anyone will click on report file name i am calling a JavaScript method which will display the parameters required for report generation and using below code

```
function displayParams(reportName) {

    prmRptName = reportName;
    param = new actuate.Parameter("panel");
    console.log("Display Params"+param);
    alert(param);
    document.getElementById("reportsForm1:reportsTable").style.display = 'none';
    param.setReportName("Applications/Sure Project/Report Designs/"
            + prmRptName);
    param.submit(function() {
        document.getElementById("backbutton").style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById("run").style.visibility = 'visible';
    });
    // console.log("Display Params");
}
```

but this line of code

```
param = new actuate.Parameter("panel");
```

throwing exception

> actuate.Parameter is not a constructor

Any idea what i am doing wrong . here `panel` is a id of `DIV` component which is inside the `XHTML` page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolve ,cause of problem is **Birt Server URL**

i was trying this code

```
function initReportExplr() {
    actuate.load("viewer");
    actuate.load("parameter");
    var reqOps = new actuate.RequestOptions();
    actuate.initialize("http://locahost:8700", reqOps,
                            "administrator", "", "");
    }
```

while it should be like this

```
function initReportExplr() {
    actuate.load("viewer");
    actuate.load("parameter");
    var reqOps = new actuate.RequestOptions();
    actuate.initialize("http://locahost:8700/iportal", reqOps,
                            "administrator", "", "");
    }
```